# VBA Deleting Visible Rows of a Table - Run-time error '1004': 'Delete method of Range class failed'

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to delete all rows with a value of "N", "X", or "V" in column 5. The data is stored in a table called "Table1". The data set is quite large which is why I was trying to filter then mass delete instead of looping through each row.

The below code is throwing the error Run-time error '1004': 'Delete method of Range class failed' and I can't for the life of me figure out why. Can anyone point me in the direction of what I'm missing here? I feel like I've successfully used similar code to do the same function before.

```
'Remove N/X/V records
wsLF.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:= _
        Array("N", "V", "X"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
LastRow = wsLF.Range("D" & wsLF.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
wsLF.Range("$A$1:$W$" & LastRow).Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete '~~~~~Error on this line
wsLF.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=5
```

Comment: You will get an error if there are no visible cells - you should consider splitting that line up into two - first get the range, then delete if there are any rows to remove.  You need to wrap up the first part in `On Error Resume Next`-`On Error Goto 0` or trap the error in the case of no visible rows.

Comment: True, but in this case I have 843 visible cells.

Comment: Is the sheet protected at all?

Comment: Neither the sheet nor the workbook are protected

Comment: I have no issues manually deleting with the `delete sheet row` button

Comment: I'd still try splitting the line to see if you can narrow down the problem.

Comment: I tried that with `.select` then `selection.delete` to no avail as well. the error remains on the delete line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for me (Max Russell also has the same `EntireRow` comment)

```
Dim rngVis As Range, tbl As ListObject

Set tbl = wsLF.ListObjects(1)

tbl.Range.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=Array("N", "V", "X"), _
                     Operator:=xlFilterValues

On Error Resume Next
Set rngVis = tbl.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
On Error GoTo 0

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
If Not rngVis Is Nothing Then rngVis.Delete 'no EntireRow
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

tbl.Range.AutoFilter Field:=5
```

Comment: Thanks, Tim! Is it safe to assume that `EntireRow.Delete` doesn't work because part of the row is contained within the object/table?

Comment: I'd guess so, Yes.

Answer (score 3):

Try referencing the range from the list object. Also, remove the `EntireRow` element. I suddenly remember that causing me issues before!

```
wsLF.ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete
```

Answer (score 0):

When the last filtered row is deleted, the function

```
SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```

becomes extinct and the working Delete method finds itself without additional cells, so it throws an exception.

The same happens if you try to use the function

SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

after the filter yielded no lines. this function cannot be resolved into any range, thus any method will throw an exception.

As it is mentioned above using

```
Set rngVis = tbl.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```

solves the problem, because it makes that range persistent and delete method works fine till the end.

Answer (score 0):

I widely used `EntireRow.Delete` in all my tables which generally were an SQL connections and has been perfectly working all the time.

But now it is first time someone used embedded PowerQuery query. And the above does not work crashing with `Delete method of Range class failed` error message.

Also `.Delete` with `[Shift]` option does not work, because of `Can't move cells in a filtered range or table.` error.

The only way is to disable `DisplayAlerts` and use `.Delete` only due to deleting entire rows is the default (otherwise you will see a dialog box).

We all need to acustom to this case as more and more users want to use PowerQuery instead of SQL.